# Field not found in class

Tags: php, function, class, model

I'm trying to match a users availability to a Group inside a function.

The problem is I can't figure out how to call the Model (getAllAvailability) into an array so I can check it against the group table. I could just be going about it all wrong.

This is as close as I can get, but on the line:

```
foreach($this->availability as $key => $value)
```

availability is not found :(

Here is my full code:

```
public function find()
    {


        /**Find groups that are not closed and send to group_find page */
        array('availability' => AvailabilityModel::getAllAvailability());
        foreach($this->availability as $key => $value) {
            GroupModel::getMatchingGroup($value->hour);

            if ($value->hour == 1600){

                /**Redirect::to('group_add user to group and check for max group size'); */
                Redirect::to('group/group_find');
            }
```

After `var_dump()`

```
array(3) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#8 (4) { ["user_id"]=> string(1) "2"
["availability_id"]=> string(1) "8" ["day"]=> string(1) "1" ["hour"]=> 
string(4) "1200" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#9 (4) { ["user_id"]=> 
string(1) "2" ["availability_id"]=> string(1) "9" ["day"]=> string(1) 
"3" ["hour"]=> string(4) "1800" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#10 (4) { 
["user_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["availability_id"]=> string(2) "10" 
["day"]=> string(1) "3" ["hour"]=> string(4) "1600" } }
```

Comment: You're not really showing us enough code, however you're creating an array on `array('availability' => AvailabilityModel::getAllAvailability());` but you're not assigning it to a variable. Could that be your problem?

Comment: what does `var_dump(AvailabilityModel::getAllAvailability());` look like?

Comment: When I var_dump i get
array(3) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#8 (4) { ["user_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["availability_id"]=> string(1) "8" ["day"]=> string(1) "1" ["hour"]=> string(4) "1200" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#9 (4) { ["user_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["availability_id"]=> string(1) "9" ["day"]=> string(1) "3" ["hour"]=> string(4) "1800" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#10 (4) { ["user_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["availability_id"]=> string(2) "10" ["day"]=> string(1) "3" ["hour"]=> string(4) "1600" } }

Comment: @AndreasIndahl - I tried assigning it to a variable, but i couldn't define one inside a function...I'm a total newb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@SaidKholov - wow, I got it. I don't know how long I've been working on this and it wasn't until I asked for a bit of help that I was able to figure it out. I was thinking about your var_dump and I realized that I was trying to make the results an array, when they are already an array.
 So getting rid of the make array line, I have:

```
/**Find groups that are not closed and send to group_find page */
        foreach(NewguyModel::getAllAvailability() as $key => $value) {
            GroupModel::getMatchingGroup($value->hour);
        }if ($value->hour == 1600){

                /**Redirect::to('group_add user to group and check for max group size'); */
                Redirect::to('note');
            }
```